# Resque - undefined method 'perform' for class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I'm not having much luck with background queues at the moment. I'm attempting to get Resque to work. I've installed redis and the Resque gem.

Redis is running. A worker is running (rake resque:work QUEUE=simple). Using the web interface I can see that the worker is running and awaiting a job.

When I run 'rake get_updates', the job is queued but fails. I've tried it both with def self.perform and def perform.

**clockwork.rake**

```
task :get_updates => :environment do
    Resque.enqueue(GetUpdates)
end
```

**Class file (app/workers/get_updates.rb)**

```
class GetUpdates
    @queue = :simple

    def perform

        puts "Running GetUpdates"

    end

end
```

**Error Message**

```
undefined method `perform' for GetUpdates:Class
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bundler/gems/resque-620d354454b8/lib/resque/job_performer.rb:79:in `perform_job'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bundler/gems/resque-620d354454b8/lib/resque/job_performer.rb:46:in `execute_job'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bundler/gems/resque-620d354454b8/lib/resque/job_performer.rb:25:in `perform'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`perform` method should be class instance method.

```
class GetUpdates
  @queue = :simple

  def self.perform
    puts "Running GetUpdates"
  end

end
```

Comment: Sorry to interrupt here, I think OP has mentioned that he has tried self.perform too.

Comment: I must've had an off moment. I restarted redis and resque, after changing it to self.perform and it seems to work now. The task isn't doing what I want yet but it's no longer erroring. Cheers.

Comment: Glad that your problem has been resolved. As Tulentsev suggested, it should be a class instance method. Please accept any of the answer which you feel appropriate so that it would be helpful for other users.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: ah, didn't notice that. But it's definitely the cause here :)

Comment: Yeah agree with you @SergioTulentsev: Mentioned the same in my next comment ;)

Comment: I had the same problem.  The fix is most certainly to change it to self.perform, but this did not work for me right off the bat (even after killing all related processes).  What eventually did work was going into http://localhost:3000/resque/failed and deleting the failed job, and THEN restarting all processes.  I'm not sure if this was simply down to timing, but at this point at least everything is working!  Thx guys.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try restarting resque after changing the method to self.perform. Quit the rake resque and start again after changing the method name to self.perform. This should work for sure.